# What is the branch number of this matrix?

Tags: matrix-multiplication, mds

We have the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

What is the branch number?

Is this a MDS marix?

Comment: Can any matrix with a 0 entry be MDS?

Comment: @poncho I would not ask, if I would know. But I suspect it can't be.

Comment: Hint: what's the definition of MDS?

Comment: Also, the answer depends on the ring that the matrix is based on.  This matrix is singular if the matrix elements are $GF(3)$

Comment: @poncho, you're right that a zero in $A$ constrains the rank. Having all nonzero entries over $GF(2)$ (thus all 1's) results in a singular $A$ and a (relatively) bad code.

Comment: @kodlu It seems relatively good to me, if it has branch number 4, compared to MDS with branch number 5.

Comment: @LightBit, sure it is almost optimal, if you wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix is not MDS over $GF(2)$; No binary MDS codes exist and non nonbinary (over $GF(2^n)$ MDS codes would have this generator whose scalar entries are in the field $GF(2)$). Over $GF(2^n)$ The branch number, which is the minimum weight of the corresponding linear code is 4, in $GF(2^n)$ for all $n$. This covers all possible fields of interest for crypto.

Note that you just need to take the given matrix, call it $A,$ form $G=[I | A]$ over the relevant field and determine the minimum weight of the resulting code. Magma (and GAP, Pari, Python) can do this for you easily. This code turns out to be a quasi-cyclic code over the fields $GF(2^n)$ with minimum distance 4.

**Edit:** It seems that 4 is the limit for the minimum distance of this type of code. In particular a $16\times16$ version, still has minimum distance only 4, for the fields $GF(2^n)$ where $n=1,2,\ldots,8.$ I assume $n=8$ is of interest to the OP, since it corresponds to having bytes as code symbols, as in AES.

This was checked on Magma as well.

Comment: So 16 x 16 matrix like this would have branch number 16?

Comment: @LightBit unfortunately no, see the edit.