# AES difference propagation

Tags: aes, differential-analysis

when does active S box count reduce in AES difference propagation?
what is the relationship between active S-boxes and MixColumns?
can you please explain it with an example?

Comment: Do you mean does increasing the active SBox count reduce the probability of the propagated differentials?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second part of your question:

The AES MixColumns operator ensures that the 8 bytes (4 in the input column 4 in the output column) form the codewords of an MDS code over $GF(2^8)$, which means the minimum weight of the code, which is 5, equals the number of nonzero bytes.

Any nonzer byte contributes 1 to the minimum weight, by definition of Hamming Weight over $GF(2^8)$. A nonzero symbol has weight 1, regardless of how many bits of the eight is nonzero.

So the number of active Sboxes is at least five.

See the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35073/what-is-the-branch-number-of-this-matrix) 
and the following [link](https://wiki.cse.buffalo.edu/cse545/content/mds-codes) for more details: